# Open installed app inside fragment using button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on a launcher that is in a view pager. My issue is that I don't know how to make it to where, if the user clicks a button it opens quick office app, when they click the flash cards button it opens the flashcard app. I have made that is installed on the device!

The buttons have been declared properly!!

UI xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFe5e5e5"
    android:gravity="center"
   >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/drive_bg"
        android:text="My Drive"
        android:onClick="drive"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_bg"
        android:text="Flashcards"
         android:onClick="flashcards"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/plus_bg"
         android:onClick="adddoc"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF777777"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus_bg"
        android:text="+"
         android:onClick="addflashcard"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF777777" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's my code for the UI:

```
package com.sibext.android_shelf;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


import com.d4a.tobias.R;

public class Three extends Fragment  {

    Button drivebtn;
    Button adddrivebtn;
    Button fcbtn;
    Button addfcbtn;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, container, false);
            drivebtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            adddrivebtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
            fcbtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            addfcbtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);





    return v;



    }





}
```

any help would be amazing

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to process click events:

- to use setOnClickListener() for you Button object, for example:

  v.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
      @Override
      public void onClick (View button) {
          //do your stuff 
     } 
  }
- or to use onClick attribute in you xml layout. In this case methods for click events have to be declared in Activity even if buttons are in fragment.

If you are interested in launching an app, you have to create an appropriate intent (that includes a package name, action=MAIN, category=LAUNCHER) and start new activity. Similar launch logs you can see in logcat when your application starts.